# Enable plugins for a specific user role

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I've created a new user role(based on shop manager) with user role editor, i need to show a custom plugin for this role.

Thanks

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'custom_role', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "custom" role
  add_action( 'some_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );
}

function my_plugin_menu() { add_options_page('My Plugin Settings', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-settings', 'my_plugin_admin_page'); }
```

Comment: you could relaize this kind of behaviour with the help of a plugin aka restrict user access. try one of [these](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/search/access+manager/) (not all are fitting your needs, but the first two and some others should do, what you are looking for)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

if ( is_myrole() ) 
{
    add_action( 'some_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );
}

function my_plugin_menu() 
{
    add_options_page('My Plugin Settings', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-plugin-settings', 'my_plugin_admin_page');
}

Comment: Inside the functions.php ?

Comment: Yes, just change values to what they should be.

Comment: Ok so i've to check the user role and use the boolean.

Comment: If answer is correct please marked it, so other people having similar problems. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't appear the menu

Comment: Edit question with your code..let me check it out.